# style.display='none' doesn't work on option tags in chrome, but it does in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, coding-style, google-chrome

ok, heres some sample code that demonstrates the problem.
if i click the button in firefox, the first option disappears.
if i click the button in chrome, nothing happens, or rather if i inspect the first option, it does have the attribute "style='display:none'" but the option itself on the html page is not hidden.

```
<form>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].style.display='none'" value="hide option 1">
</form>
```

why doesn't this work in chrome?

Comment: Works on Chrome now. IE is last as usual, still giving us unnecessary headaches.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The workaround is to remove the `option` elements in response to your event and add them back if and when they are needed. IIRC, IE will not allow you to set the `display` to `none` on `option` elements. I would advise storing the removed elements in an array so that you can easily add them back in.

Comment: Interesting fact, Chrome Canary (at least 40.0.2179.0) respects display:none on options. I think firefox does as well.

Comment: @GEverding Firefox won't initially show the element, but you can still select the hidden elements with your keyboard (at which point they will be shown). You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gefz928j/. Bottom line is you shouldn't use `display:none` to *remove* options from a list.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, You should when the removal is temporary. Removing the `display:none` is much faster than reattaching the whole list.

Comment: Chrome now supports display:none in the release build. Interesting, though, that <option> would not hide when set to display none. I personally think that it shouldn't follow different rules than literally every other element in the dom, even if it is a browser form element.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have to remove the `<option>` instead of 'hiding' it. If it's not a solution for you, try disabling it.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].disabled='disabled'
```

PS: You might want to reconsider using `getElementsByTagName('option')`, can get messy if you have more `<select>` elements.

Comment: was just using that command as a simple example to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
removeIt = function()
{
    var theSelect = document.getElementById("theSelect");
    var theOption = document.getElementById("theOption");
    theSelect.removeChild(theOption);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="theSelect">
<option>1</option>
<option id="theOption">2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="removeIt()" value="remove it!"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I quickly got it working by simply removing it from its parentNode... obviously this is going to be a hack.
I'll try to find a better solution for you =)

By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: It isn't deleting it.  It is simply removing it from the parent node.  You can, later, call theSelect.appendChild(theOption);  ..Although this would probably screw up the order [in my example it would become 1, 3, 2]  Still trying to think of a solution.

Comment: Update: Sadly, I can't think of a better way.  Perhaps, when you first do the removeChild() option, you could copy childNodes to another array, so you can keep order.  Then when you reappend, you have to remove everything and reappend everything.  Inefficient, but I can't think of a better way >_>

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather why that works in any browser at all?

The options are not used as elements in the page, they contain the information to show in the select element. Some browsers let you apply some styles to the options, but generally you can't really expect cross browser support for any styles at all.

If you want to keep an option from being displayed, you just have to remove it from the select.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't say what it is that you don't like, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: According to HTML specs display property is applicable to all elements, including option and optgroup.

Comment: @Denis Otkidach: Yes, in HTML, but this is no longer HTML, it's objects in the DOM. You would have to replace the entire select element with new HTML to get it parsed again.

Answer (score 1):

As my solution is (asp.net), I will try to do it by that way.

1. Create a dropdowlist will all ListItems
2. Using javascript to add or remove ListItems (Note: add option need same value and text in asp:dropdownlist items)

---

```
function removeOptionSelected() {
    var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl_DropList');
    var i;
    for (i = ddl.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        ddl.remove(i);
    }
}
function addOptions3() {
    removeOptionSelected();
    var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl_DropList');
    var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');

    elOptNew.text = 'Monthly Top Producer(Project)';
    elOptNew.value = 'GCE';
    try {
        ddl.add(elOptNew, null); // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
    }
    catch (ex) {
        ddl.add(elOptNew); // IE only
    }
    elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
    elOptNew.text = 'Monthly Top Leaders - DD';
    elOptNew.value = 'DRE';
    try {
        ddl.add(elOptNew, null); // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
    }
    catch (ex) {
        ddl.add(elOptNew); // IE only
    }
    elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
    elOptNew.text = 'Monthly Top Leaders - SDD';
    elOptNew.value = 'DRESDD';
    try {
        ddl.add(elOptNew, null); // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
    }
    catch (ex) {
        ddl.add(elOptNew); // IE only
    }
    elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
    elOptNew.text = 'Monthly Top Leaders - GD';
    elOptNew.value = 'GRE';
    try {
        ddl.add(elOptNew, null); // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
    }
    catch (ex) {
        ddl.add(elOptNew); // IE only
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For deleting of one option from select form may be used jQuery's $().eq().remove() or $().remove().

Similar was my deleting of one table row from table:

```
$('form table tr').eq(1).remove();
```

where:

```
$('form table tr')
```

say that removed element will be table row (tr) from table enclosed in form (form table).

```
eq(1)
```

say that removed will be the second element (element with index number 1)

```
remove()
```

say that element will be removed.

But when this should be used on option, then all needed would be (for example):

```
$('select option[value="1"]').remove();
```

because it is simplier to find option by value than by index number (unless you would have more ioption with the same value - but it is nonsense, to have such options). Using of index number is good if you have not any else that you may use to find removed element.

Also you may, of course, add form name or form name and select name (or id, or class) into element identification

```
$('form[name="date"] selection[name="day"] option[value="1"]').remove();
$('form#date selection#day option[value="1"]').remove();
```

but the first option is better - and more logical, due to server-side processes, where you need to use attribute *name* instead *id* or *class*.

Comment: `$('select option[value="1"]').remove();` is working

Answer (score 0):

I know this is now old, but you could - especially if you are using jQuery change parent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            function sourceListChange() {
                var oVisible = $('#destList');
                var newCategory = $( "#sourceList" ).val()||'';
                var oToShow = $();

                oHiddenDestList.append(oVisible.find('option'));

                if (newCategory) {
                    oToShow = oHiddenDestList.find('.'+newCategory);
                }           

                if (oToShow.length==0) {
                    oVisible.append (oHiddenDestList.find('.NA'));
                } else if (oToShow.length!=1) {
                    oVisible.append (oHiddenDestList.find('.SELECT'));
                }
                oVisible.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

                oVisible.append (oToShow);
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                sourceListChange();
            });

            var oHiddenDestList = $(document.createElement('select'));

        </script>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        Select a parent group:
        <select id="sourceList" onchange="sourceListChange()">
            <option class="SELECT" value="" selected disabled>Please Select</option>
            <option value="veg">Vegetables</option>
            <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
        </select>

        <select id="destList">
            <option class="SELECT" value="*" selected disabled>Please Select</option>
            <option class="NA" value="" selected disabled>Not Applicable</option>
            <option class="fruit">Apple</option>
            <option class="fruit">Bannana</option>
            <option class="veg">Carrot</option>
            <option class="veg">Pea</option>
        </select>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

var check = function(r) { return r.test(ua);};

var isChrome = check(/chrome/);
`
var f=document.getElementById('select_tag_id');

f.options[i].style.display='none';

if (isChrome) f.size=2;
```

The select box changed to 2 size (like multiple), but working.
This trick don't working under safari :(