# Hide options of select according to option value

Tags: jquery, select, hide

Given following HTML

```html
<select name="IBE1$IBE_NurFlug1$ddl_Abflughafen" id="IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_ddl_Abflughafen" class="dropdownlist" style="width: 99%;">
    <option value="Antalya;TR">Antalya</option>
    <option value="Berlin;DE">Berlin</option>
    <option value="Duesseldorf;DE">Duesseldorf</option>
    <option value="Frankfurt;DE">Frankfurt</option>
    <option value="Hamburg;DE">Hamburg</option>
    <option value="Hannover;DE">Hannover</option>
    <option value="Köln-Bonn;DE">Köln-Bonn</option>
    <option value="Leipzig;DE">Leipzig</option>
    <option value="München;DE">München</option>
    <option value="Stuttgart;DE">Stuttgart</option>
</select>
```

How can I hide all options with ;TR in the value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
$("select > option[value*='TR']").remove()
```

EDIT:

Or if you know that 'TR' is always at the end, then

```
$("select > option[value$='TR']").remove()
```

Not sure how much more efficient the above is compared to searching the entire `value` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted your solution to my needs: 

    $(function() { 
       $('#IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_ddl_Abflughafen > option[value*="TR"]').hide();
    });

Comment: @ceyago - Ahh yeah, I misread your requirement. `remove()` actually gets rid of the `<option>` which isn't what you wanted. Using `hide()` works better.

Comment: Ya its working fine. i have tried following.
$("select > option[value$='TR']").remove()

Comment: As pointed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-displaynone-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefox, WebKit ignores display:none on option tags. So you should really remove and add them as you need.

Comment: what if i have two select ?

Comment: @s4suryapal I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you have more than one select give them unique ids and change **select** to **#select_id** where #select_id is the id of the select you wish to work on. I hope that makes sense.