# How to hide and show select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very very new to jQuery. I Googled a lot before I'm asking, though it looks silly but for me its complicated.

I have a simple `<select>` list which has around 4 values like this image shown below.

[image]

Now at runtime, I want to hide the options and show based on index or value names in jQuery. How can I achieve this?.

My drop down box has a `div` region and simple `select` option with set of values. Please provide me a simple example.

Sample code

```
<Div ID = "abcd">
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

In this how to hide Volvo/Opel at run time?... like i want to show and hide these options dynamically.

Like Ex: When a button is pressed i want to hide Volvo. Similarly if another button is pressed i want to display Volvo back.

Comment: Have you taken any of the tutorials? http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Can you give an example of the indices or names that the options would be based off of?

Comment: @Samsquanch, i have updated the question.. kindly help

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to hide the whole select you should give your select or the div containing your select an id and then you can do like :

```
<div id="mySelect" >your select tag here </div>

$('mySelect').show(); // or $('mySelect').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/show/

if you would like to hide the option you can do like below :

```
$("#edit-field-service-sub-cat-value option[value=" + title + "]").hide();
```

To be more specific to your code :

```
<div id="abcd">
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>

title = 'volvo';
$("#mySelect option[value=" + title + "]").hide();
```

like in this post : 
[Hide options in a select list using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery)

or remove it :

[JQuery: Hide options of select according to option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164690/jquery-hide-options-of-select-according-to-option-value)

Comment: thanks, in this case edit-field-service-sub-cat-value is my DIV ID, tittle is Value like Volvo, or opel etc.. correct???

Comment: Yes that was just an example from stackoverflow you just replace that with your id.

Comment: keep in mind hiding the element if it is currently selected (in some browsers) still displays the value as the current index (as well as selectedIndex property) however the value (option) is no longer visible for selection. This could cause problems in the future. I would be more inclined to 'detach' and 'attach' the element to and from the list.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly, i tried like this,    var title = "Volvo";
 $(Bus + "-Names" + "option[value=" + title + "]").hide();. But not worked :(

Comment: In the selector you should put space between the id and the option like this :

`var title = "Volvo"; $(Bus + "-Names" + " option[value=" + title + "]").hide();`

let me know if this works.