# remove works but not hide?

Tags: jquery, safari

creating a filter for a select menu and having a few problems!

the first one is

```
$("#filterContentMenu option:contains(a)").hide();
```

doesn't work but

```
$("#filterContentMenu option:contains(a)").remove();
```

does.

Actually this only seem to be a problem in safari! Works in firefox?

Comment: What do the elements look like in Safari when you inspect them (What's their computed CSS?)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-displaynone-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.hide()` sets an element's `display` to `none`.  You can't set an `<option>` to `display: none`, it won't work in all browsers.  You can remove them and retain a reference to them, though:

```
var removed = $("#filterContentMenu option:contains(a)").remove();

// later that day...
removed.appendTo("#filterContentMenu");
```

Answer (score 1):

"Hiding" (setting to `display: none`) options isn't very well supported in several browsers. It is really better to delete and recreate them.