# Trying to hide some options tag with jquery doesn't work IE, Safari and Opera

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide some `<options>` tags with jquery but it doesn't seem to work.

- I want to hide all options that have the `rel` attribute.
- Show only options for `rel='3'`

This code works on FF and Chrome. Doesn't work IE, Safari and Opera.

Here is my jsfiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/RnfqW/4/

Here is the markup and script:

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect" >
    <option value=''></option>
    <option rel='1' value='1A'>1A</option>
    <option rel='1' value='1B'>1B</option>
    <option rel='2' value='2A'>2A</option>
    <option rel='2' value='2B'>2B</option>
    <option rel='2' value='2C'>2C</option>
    <option rel='3' value='3A'>3A</option>
    <option rel='3' value='3B'>3B</option>
    <option rel='3' value='3C'>3C</option>
    <option rel='3' value='3D'>3D</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
$("#myselect [rel]").hide(); // hide all options
$("#myselect [rel=3]").show(); // hide whow only rel=3 options
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove works but not hide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309787/remove-works-but-not-hide)

Comment: Refer to the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo). It is solved.

Comment: The problem with removing is you can't recreate it back.

Comment: @Boris: removing it from the document doesn't destroy it if you assign it to a variable, and you can add it back when you need it again.  See the duplicate questions.  Cloning and deleting is a poor approach in comparison.

Comment: @AndyE: you're probably right, I'm not an expert on this subject. Was just trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide or show options. What you must do is clone your select and delete option tags you don't want.

EDIT : something like that http://jsfiddle.net/RnfqW/5/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code and customize it. I hope it will be useful...

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.extend({
        slidingSelect: function(options)
        {
            var select= $(this);
            var selector=select.selector;
           var selectedValue="";//=select.val();

            var divToggle=$("<div>"+selectedValue+"select Complaint<span style='float:right;'>&#x25BC;</span></div>").attr({id:select.attr("id")+"Toggle"}).click(function(){
                $(selector).slideToggle();
            }).insertBefore(select);

            select.attr("size",6);  
            select.change(function(){
                divToggle.html(select.val()+"<span style='float:right;'>&#x25BC;</span>");
                $(selector).slideToggle();
            });

        }       
    });
    $("#complaint").hide().slidingSelect();

});
```