# jQuery "visible" doesn't work in all browsers, but in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-selectors, cross-browser

I've made a very simple fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/sZR2f/), and you can check it out in different browsers.

It only works in Firefox. In other words, seems that `$('#select-tag-id option:visible')` doesn't work in other browsers. What's wrong? Is it a jQuery bug?

The code is:

```
<select id='items'>
    <option value='1' style='display: none;'>One</option>
    <option value='1' style='display: block;'>Two</option>
    <option value='1' style='display: block;'>Three</option>
    <option value='1' style='display: none;'>Four</option>
</select>
```

and the JavaScript (jQuery code) is:

```
$(function(){
    alert($('#items option:visible').length);
});
```

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14672

Comment: It's worth noting that the `multiple` attribute does not affect the result in any browser, even though the attribute causes as many options to be displayed as the height of the select allows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a jQuery bug - just (yet another) browser difference.

IE won't let you set `display:none` on option elements ([style.display='none' doesnt work on option tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo)).

If you look at your *fiddle* in both FF and IE, you'll see that the `<select>` still contains all four elements in IE, but only two in FF, regardless of jQuery being present.

The solution would probably be to actually remove the elements and replace when needed.

Comment: Well, well. Let put IE aside (just like always with this damn browser). But what about Opera, or Chrome? Don't they also support `display: none` on options? Of course they do. But seems that they can't filter `option` tags based on their visibility state.

Comment: This question just came up again [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902335/why-i-cannot-grab-option-tag-with-visible-selector), and preliminary research does not appear to turn up *anything* about this discrepancy, not even in any browser's public bug tracker. How very quaint. I suppose this is all we have for now.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `:hidden` and `:visible` don't work on `<option>`'s

You could try to use `disabled="disabled"` see:

http://jsfiddle.net/sZR2f/7/