# using .css('display')=="none" in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, visibility

I'm trying to test for something's visibility with

```
$(this).css('display')=="none";
```

The problem is, it works in chrome, FF...but not in IE. I've tried IE 8 and 9 so far.

Does anyone know a work around? This is very frustrating as a bunch of people still use IE and I don't want to lose that bunch of people.

Comment: You can use `$(this).is(':visible')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$(this).is(":visible")` for a cross-browser solution.

From the docs:

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/
and [How to tell if an element is visible](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-element-is-visible/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820824/jquery-visible-doesnt-work-in-all-browsers-but-in-firefox
This may help you.

Comment: Mine is a td element. However, looking at your documentation...It seems like my items aren't actually visible as my visibility is simply CSS. Then...how does it work in chrome?