# Why I cannot grab <option> tag with :visible selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As per the [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/),

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

I had inspected the option tag, it seems there is no css property set with it in order to ignore its space from the DOM. Though, while i selecting the `option` tag using `:visible` selector it is not selecting anything. It sounds mysterious to me.

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option selected=true>test</option>
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
    <option>test4</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
console.log($('select option:visible').length); // Length always returns 0
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v85yR/)

Can anyone explain credibly, what is going on behind this.?

Comment: They are not visible until its 'dropped down'.

Comment: it returns length  5 for me

Comment: @Sudharsan I am testing this in latest version of chrome..! what browser are you using.?

Comment: @StephenMuecke But there is no css property set with it to vanish it from the DOM while it is not dropped down..

Comment: Not sure but I suspect that's a browser function (internally it must set `option` to `display:none` otherwise it would be visible on the screen)

Comment: The `multiple` attribute does not seem to affect the result in any browser. http://jsfiddle.net/v85yR/13 Speaking of which, the `selected` attribute is much like it in that it doesn't have a proper value as it's a Boolean attribute, so in HTML just `<option selected>` will do.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy it returns length 5 for me too firefox 30.0 and chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m

Comment: @BoltClock Just now tested your fiddle, It is still displaying 0 in `chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 m`

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy: That's why I said it "does not seem to affect the result in any browser".

Comment: @Vikram: What platform are you on? Chrome/Win 36.0.1985.125 returns 0 for me.

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14672

Comment: It seems that jquery can't check the visibility of `option` :/