# knockoutjs: issue with option tags and visibility

Tags: knockout.js

It seems that we have a different behaviour between two groups of browsers on the visibility of the OPTIONS of an html SELECT tag:
if I set visible to false in the OPTION tag, the relevant drop down list item is hidden in Chrome and Firefox but it's still visible in IE8 and Safari.

http://jsfiddle.net/v8gyG/12/

Do you have any suggestion or am I doing something wrong?
Please be aware that I can't use jquery.tmpl.js in this case, only hard coded SELECT/OPTION tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it was asked long time ago, but it's worth an answer since I found this question in Google while looking for an answer myself. I figured the solution so I'm back here to share it. Two years and "visible" still doesn't work**, so I checked "if" binding. Data-binding it inside option element made it hidden but selectable. Knockout has also something called: "containerless control flow syntax".

This works for me:

```
   <!-- ko if: category.parent == 0 -->
     <option data-bind="value: category.name, text: category.name"></option>
   <!-- /ko -->
```

It works because if hides DOM. From knockout website:

> if plays a similar role to the visible binding. The difference is
>   that, with visible, the contained markup always remains in the DOM and
>   always has its data-bind attributes applied - the visible binding just
>   uses CSS to toggle the container element’s visibility. The if binding,
>   however, physically adds or removes the contained markup in your DOM,
>   and only applies bindings to descendants if the expression is true.

You can read more in documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Check various options here: http://jsfiddle.net/v8gyG/24/

** "visible" works in Chrome 27 and Firefox 21 but not with multiselect in Chrome.

`<!-- ko if: -->` works also in IE 10 and with multiselect in Chrome.

Comment: to me looks like its not a solution, in this case we can't bind selected object

Answer (score 2):

When you set the `visible` attribute, knockout just adds a `style="display: none"` attribute to the `<option>` element. This is not valid in IE. See:

[style.display='none' doesn't work on option tags in chrome, but it does in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo)

Answer (score 1):

The code suggests you are using the select for choosing a page number. Consider creating a DependentObservable that contains the options.

```
viewModel.Pages = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
  var pages = []
  for (var i=0 ; i < this.NumPages() ; ++i) {
    pages.push({label: "Pag " + (i+1), value: (i+1)})
  }
  return pages;
}, viewModel)
```

And in the view:

```
<select data-bind="value: Page, options: Pages, optionsText: 'label'></select>
```

When Page 2 is chosen, the `Page` variable will contain {label: 'Pag 2', value: 2}