# Style With razor tag Didn't work in IE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [style.display=‘none’ doesnt work on option tags in chrome, but it does in firefox, anyone know why? or a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo)

```
 @For Each myItem In Data
      @<option style="display: none; " value="@myItem.dataCode" child="@myItem.dataCodeChild" >
          @myItem.dataCode
      </option>                                
 Next myItem
```

All Option tags still show but style's in IE. element still show style="display: none; ". 
But it work on Chrome. How can fix it to work in IE.?

Comment: In which IE? IE6,IE7,IE8,IE9,IE10?

Answer (score 1):

<option>  doesn't officially support the style="display: none" attribute

See this other question [style.display='none' doesn't work on option tags in chrome, but it does in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo)

Answer (score 0):

Resolve your issue on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/878331/1643075
and [demo](http://jsbin.com/anoci)

Comment: In VB.NET you need that @ to be there.