# Display:none; in select multiple doesn't work on IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm new here, and a junior developer. I have one problem with IE8, my code works fine in Firefox, but in IE doesn't work at all.

I have 2 select multiple in my code, and I want to show a few of the options of the second select for the choices in the first one.

HTML:

```
    <form name="formMenu">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <select multiple name="selectOne" title="selectOne" class="selectOne" 
             style="width:180px;height:60px">
                <option value="abc" onclick="Javascript:obtainSecondChoices()">  
                    abc
                </option>
                <option value="def" onclick="Javascript:obtainSecondChoices()">  
                    def
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <select multiple name="selectTwo" title="selectTwo" class="selectTwo"
             style="width:180px;height:60px">
                <option class="abc" value="selTwoOpt1" style="display:none;">
                    selTwoOpt1
                </option>
                <option class="def" value="selTwoOpt2" style="display:none;">
                    selTwoOpt2
                </option>
                <option class="abc" value="selTwoOpt3" style="display:none;">
                    selTwoOpt3
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

JavaSript:

```
    function obtainSecondChoices(){
        var fstSelects = document.formMenu.selectOne;
            for(var i = 0 ; i < fstSelects.length; i++){
                var fstSelect = fstSelects[i];
                if(fstSelect.selected){
                    var scndSelects = document.formMenu.selectTwo;
                    for(var j = 0; j< scndSelects.length; j++){
                    if(scndSelects[j].className == fstSelect.value){
                    scndSelects[j].style.display = '';
                    }
                    }
                } else {
                    var scndSelects = document.formMenu.selectTwo;
                    for(var j = 0; j< scndSelects.length; j++){
                        if(scndSelects[j].className == fstSelect.value){
                            scndSelects[j].style.display = 'none';
                            scndSelects[j].selected = false;
                        }
                }
                }
            }
    }
```

This should show or hide and unselect the second choices depending on what you select in the first options.

As I said, it works fine in Firefox, but Internet Explorer not even initially hidden with display: none;

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Try to avoid adding `onclick` event handler for select's options. Instead, use `onchange` in the select itself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I'll try to use onchange instead of onclick from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code: There is little changes with your HTML as using temp `Select` tag is used.

HTML:

```
 <form name="formMenu">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <select multiple="multiple" name="selectOne" title="selectOne" class="selectOne"
                    style="width: 180px; height: 60px" onchange="obtainSecondChoices()">
                    <option value="abc">abc </option>
                    <option value="def">def </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <select multiple="multiple" name="selectTwo" title="selectTwo" class="selectTwo"
                    style="width: 180px; height: 60px">
                </select>
                <select name="selectTemp" id="selectTemp" style="display: none;">
                    <option class="abc" value="selTwoOpt1">selTwoOpt1 </option>
                    <option class="def" value="selTwoOpt2">selTwoOpt2 </option>
                    <option class="abc" value="selTwoOpt3">selTwoOpt3 </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function obtainSecondChoices() {
            var fstSelects = document.formMenu.selectOne;
            var scndSelects = document.formMenu.selectTwo;
            scndSelects.options.length = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < fstSelects.length; i++) {
                var fstSelect = fstSelects[i];
                if (fstSelect.selected) {
                    var tempSelects = document.formMenu.selectTemp;
                    for (var j = 0; j < tempSelects.length; j++) {
                        if (tempSelects[j].className == fstSelect.value) {
                            scndSelects.options[scndSelects.options.length] = new Option(tempSelects[j].text, tempSelects[j].value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I can't, I don't have enough reputation I tried but I've reputation 8 and I need 15. When I get the 15 points I'll upvote.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
scndSelects[j].style.display = 'none';
  scndSelects[j].selected = false;
```

use

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('scndSelects');
  var i;
   i= 5 // no. of option you want to remove
ddl.remove(i);
```

Comment: In this case when you remove the option from second select then how you will add it next time

Comment: He should also implement ways to save and add options. Question was how to hide them I advised him to remove them to assure that there are no cross browser differences. IMHO