# select option using jquery fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here iam trying to get values based on `#category` selection when i select a category men or women,following select option should show the relevant options.what i did satisfied my requirement but when i try to access it using keyboard(down arrow) it shows all the options of the `#subcategory`.here is the code and fiddle.any help is thankful.

**my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JUGWU/**

**HTML:**

```
<select id="category" name="category">
<option>-select-</option>
<option value="MEN" id="menu1">MEN</option>
<option value="WOMEN" id="menu2">WOMEN</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="subcategory">
    <option></option>
<option id="Clothing" value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
<option id="Accessories" value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
<option id="Footwear" value="Footwear">Footwear</option>
<option id="Watches" value="Watches">Watches</option>
<option id="Sunglasses" value="Sunglasses">Sunglasses</option>
<option id="Bags" value="Bags">Bags</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#category").change(function() {
   var xyz = $("option:selected").attr("id");
     alert(xyz);


    if(xyz === "menu1"){
        $("#subcategory option").hide();
        $("#Clothing,#Footwear").show();

   }
 });
});
```

Comment: when I use the keyboard the select the first select element, it works fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2324250/1959948. $("#subcategory option").hide(); sets to display none the elements. I think you will need to removed them

Comment: @ j08691 ya it works but if you go down it should not show watches,bags,...even those things are visible when i use keyboard

Comment: Oooh I see what you're saying.

Comment: I think js shouldn't change element style, he must change only state of your elements. You may use this http://jsfiddle.net/Lenpv/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is not exactly addressing your problem (using keyboard(down arrow)) but I think it is IMHO a better way to do what you want. And also I used the fixed part from @user2301903 answer, just to make my point. my main point here was using the markup attributes.*

We can use our markup attributes to have less complexity, I changed your markup like this (added a `catg` attribute):

```
<select id="category" name="category">
    <option>-select-</option>
    <option value="MEN" id="menu1" catg="m">MEN</option>
    <option value="WOMEN" id="menu2" catg="w">WOMEN</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="subcategory">
    <option></option>
    <option id="Clothing" value="Clothing" catg="m">Clothing</option>
    <option id="Accessories" value="Accessories" catg="w">Accessories</option>
    <option id="Footwear" value="Footwear" catg="m">Footwear</option>
    <option id="Watches" value="Watches" catg="w">Watches</option>
    <option id="Sunglasses" value="Sunglasses" catg="w">Sunglasses</option>
    <option id="Bags" value="Bags" catg="w">Bags</option>
</select>
```

and your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#category").change(function () {
        var catg = $("option:selected").attr("catg");

        //from @user2301903 answer
        $("#subcategory option").prop('disabled', true).hide();
        $("option[catg=" + catg + "]").prop('disabled', false).show();
    });
});
```

and this is your working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JUGWU/4/);

and this one is another way of doing what you want which works even in IE: [IE_DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JUGWU/17/)

Comment: can you please mention in what way is your answer better than the user2301903.does it fetch in seo(due to HTML)??

Comment: @3bu1: it is not better than the user2301903, as you see I have used it in my answer, his answer has fixed using keyboard problem, but the whole point in mine is how to decrease the complexity, using html attributes. to be honest I'm not sure if it has anything to do with SEO.

Comment: this code is not working in ie check out the fiddle in ie once please

Comment: @3bu1: it seems that IE have some problems with jQuery 1.10.1, I changes the jQuery version and problem got solved.

Comment: which version have you changed to?

Comment: @3bu1: jQuery version 1.9.1 or earlier versions of jQuery.

Comment: when i use jquery 1.9.1 all options get displayed but they are inaccessible(disabled),that gives a very poor UI.what i need is not to be displayed.

Comment: when you hide an option in IE, it just get disabled, let fix it for you.

Comment: @3bu1: Yea, IE's hide, just disables the options so you see the greyed out options which aren't clickable. You might need to change your code for IE. One option would be to have have 2 separate dropdowns, which you hide and show as needed. Or, instead of hiding showing elements, you can remove and add them.

Comment: @3bu1: I have added a new fiddle sample which works in all browsers as you want. you can accept my answer if it is helpful.

Comment: @MehranHatami this works only in fiddle when i try it in a web page its not working.in fiddle there is a nowrap in<head> how can i get it in web page.i have tried pasting the code in head even then its not working.thank you

Comment: @3bu1: wrap the whole script in script tag and put it in the head tag.

Comment: @3bu1: come to this [ROOM](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46211/myjs) if you have any question.

Comment: it says "You must be logged in to talk." even though i am logged in.there is some problem with chat room.can you change the appending part instead of .html(); can you try using .append();

Comment: @3bu1: I have updated the DEMO check this one [IE_DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JUGWU/17/)

Comment: @MehranHatami here is the fiddle which works properly in web page check out http://jsfiddle.net/JUGWU/18/

Comment: @3bu1: So was it helpful? if it was you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your conditional. The `disabled` property doesn't allow keyboard selection. Seems to work for me.

```
$("#subcategory option").prop('disabled', true).hide();
$("#Clothing,#Footwear").prop('disabled', false).show();
```

Also, your logic breaks if a user switches from men to women.