# Why Javascript stop work?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, why my Javascript work correct on pure html - localhost, but when include code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FzgF/) - stop working, why? what is wrong? Please help me.

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<BODY>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckContact(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('email');
 if(val=='email')
   element.style.display='block';
 else
   element.style.display='none';

 var element=document.getElementById('sms');
 if(val=='sms')
   element.style.display='block';
 else
   element.style.display='none';
}
</script>
<select name="contactinfo" id="contactinfo" onchange="CheckContact(this.value);">
  <option>Select Contact Option</option>
  <option value="email" class="email">Email</option>
  <option value="sms"class="email">Text (SMS)</option>
</select><br />
<select>
<option> - </option>
<option id="email" style="display: none;">Enter Email: </option>
<option id="sms" style="display: none;">Enter Cell Number: </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

i have one question, why when include this code in wordpress page - javascript stop working?

Comment: You might want to change the title to something a little less... broad.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, especially since you didn't specify what 'working' is. What should it do?

Comment: In some browsers it isn't possible to "hide" `option` elements.

Answer (score 2):

jsfiddle lets you choose where to place the javascript code on the page in the dropdown on the left.  Change this from `onLoad` to `NoWrap - in <head>` to make your function accessible at the global scope.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't change anything for me... I don't know why but both the Email and SMS options show up on load.

Comment: @AlbertXing Make sure you hit "run" again after changing that setting.  It is now calling the `CheckContact` method when the first drop down value is changed.

Comment: I'm not the OP, just confirming your answer to upvote it if it's correct. I edited my previous comment.

Comment: Right, it's Chrome - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/

Comment: @AlbertXing ah, my mistake.  Yeah I believe the issue he has is that the function is getting defined in the onLoad handler, and so this is probably a duplicate as p.s.w.g mentions in the question's comments

Answer (score 1):

Just change your fiddle to `no-wrap in <head>`. It is working for me in Chrome.

Answer (score -2):

Well, it helps if you use '{ }'

```
'function CheckContact(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('email');
 if(val=='email') {
    element.style.display='block';
 }
 else {
    element.style.display='none';
 }
 var element=document.getElementById('sms');
 if(val=='sms') {
    element.style.display='block';
 }
 else {
    element.style.display='none';
 }
 console.log ("test");
}'
```

Put some console.log calls like the example above, until I added the '{ }' it did not work at all even in normal browser.

Comment: You’re wrong, by the way. You may want to amend your answer to be correct (if you have something to say beyond the other two answers) or delete it.