# document.getElementById().style.display = 'none'; only works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Why does this only work in Firefox?
IE and Chrome seem to ignore the style.display = 'none'
Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>


    <script language="JavaScript">
        function validateForm() {

            document.getElementById('option2').style.display = 'none';

       }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <select id="employeeID" onchange="validateForm();">
        <option value="0" id="option0">Select an Employee</option>
        <option value="1" id="option1">Employee 1</option>
        <option value="2" id="option2">Employee 2</option>
        <option value="3" id="option3">Employee 3</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works here in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/wdDz4/

Comment: @YuriyGalanter It does seem to, but my JSFiddle keeps it inside an onchange function and doesn't seem to have the same result. http://jsfiddle.net/uWQzs/

Comment: @katana314 , if you put it in a function , you need to call this function :)

Comment: It works for me in Chrome and FF, but not IE11

Comment: @Katana314 HTML cannot find the function. But if it is put in HEAD it works: http://jsfiddle.net/uWQzs/1/

Comment: same , IE look's to be as powerfull as before

Comment: IE11 doesn't seem to fire the `onchange` event.

Comment: @ssbb, the function is called from the "onchange" attribute in the HTML

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of JSFiddle's small needs; this one does seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/uWQzs/3/

Comment: possible duplicate of [style.display='none' doesnt work on option tags in chrome, but it does in firefox, anyone know why? or a workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo)

Comment: I don't think you can apply styles to an `<option>` tag.

Comment: It appears some browsers simply do not allow you to hide options. Some higher-end ones, such as Chrome and FF, might but low-end ones, such as IE, probably will not

Answer (score 2):

You should bind `change` event to your select element using `.addEventListener` method ->

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hD8SP/1/)

**Javascript**

```
function validateForm() {

    alert(); //checking if this actually works

document.getElementById('option2').style.display = 'none';

}


select_ = document.getElementById('employeeID');

select_.addEventListener('change',validateForm,false);
```

or

```
select_.onchange = validateForm;
```

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

**Safari**

[image: Safari]

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
document.getElementById('option2').style.display = 'none';
```

to

```
document.getElementById('option2').style.visibility="hidden";
```

Comment: Make sure it is actually firing.  In the validateForm function ,just add an alert('hello'); or alert(document.getElementById('option2').style.display);

Comment: I take back my comment. I forgot I still had some other debug code in. This works, but it displays the entry as a blank line, rather than removing it altogether

Answer (score -3):

Browsers such as Chrome prefer to use jQuery now instead of JavaScript so change:

```
document.getElementById('option2').style.display = 'none';
```

to read like so to hide:

```
$('#option2').hide();
```

And to show it again use:

```
$('#option2').show();
```

Comment: Well, of course, jQuery is "just" a library written in JavaScript; imho the answer is offtopic as the OP is probably perfectly fine relying on a robust, cross-browser JavaScript solution, knowing about jQuery beforehand.

Comment: Agreed.  Off-topic.  "Just use jQuery" isn't really a solution to the question.