# match select option value and show from hide in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  3 select multiple options ( 3 select box with multiple selection options).On popup i hide some options and now i want to show that option on some text base.I am confused how to match and then show that option that are hidden.I created the option values by concating some fields using `_`.My select box are like this :

```
 <select id="frsts" size="10" class="select multiselect" multiple="">
            <option value="163_0_Computer">Computer</option>
    <option value="164_4999.95_Gaming Computer">Gaming Computer</option>
    <option value="165_0_My Computer">My Computer</option>
    <option notebook="" value="25_2299.9900_Apple MacBook Pro MA464LL/A 15.4">
Apple MacBook Pro MA464LL/A 15.4" Notebook PC</option> 
 </select>
```

I have value like `163`,`164` etc .I want to match 163 with all the options value and which one have this on first `_` i want to show that option.

Answer (score -1):

```
$( "#frsts option" ).each(function(){
     var v= this.value;
    if( v.match('163') ){
        $( this ).show();
    } else {
        $( this ).hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44MG6/1/

Comment: then you can split the string with first three character then match with attr() function

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that most browsers do not allow the hiding of individual <option>s.

Comment: For hiding i am using this code .`jQuery('#frsts ').children('option[value="'+selectedthird[i]+'"]').detach();
`

Comment: hi Adda, if you not found the good option with all browsers then replace the select-option to ul li and manage it using the css it will work.

Comment: when i try `show()` and `hide()` and same for display `none`.they didn't work on chrome.I am confused where really these methods works.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo