# Chrome <Select> not large enough

Tags: html, google-chrome

On certain machines running Chrome (in *app* mode), our users are experiencing the issue in the first image.

However, when trying this myself, on the same URL, it works correctly.

There is no special CSS and it's simply a *SELECT* with various children set to `display:none;`

Broken:

[image: Broken]

Working:

[image: Working]

```
<select class="searchableList" id="searchableList" name="searchableList" tabindex="4">
  <option value="" data-worktypecode="0"></option>

  <option data-worktypecode="0" data-fieldcode="" data-entitycode="" data-specialfield="cl_namkey" data-entityfield="">Client Name</option>

  <option data-worktypecode="23" data-fieldcode="" data-entitycode="23BORR" data-specialfield="" data-entityfield="el_surname" style="display: none;">Borrower Surname (RM)</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Is it a `select`, or several styled `a`'s? A tad confused by your wording `"and it's simply a with various children"`

Comment: It's a select - I've added a sample - sorry about the `"And it's simply..."` - A SO oversight of typing `<SELECT>` in the text!

Comment: AFAIK: `display: none` on `<option>` elements works only on certain browsers. You're better off moving them somewhere else through jQuery. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo

Comment: I should add - this is an internal site - and only used in Chrome - it's on Chrome and Chrome it doesn't work :/

Comment: Well, now you know the problem: Chrome doesn't support `display: none`'s on `<option>`s, sadly. On to a fix! :D

Comment: It clearly does - as it works on some machines (on Chrome) and not on others (also Chrome)

Comment: Versioning, perhaps?

Comment: Try wrapping the `<option>` in a `<span>`, and display-none the `<span>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9234883/1255033

Comment: Who knows - Ended up, reducing the list to only those I wanted showing - `Hidden` didn't work either.

Comment: Story of every developers life. "Didn't work the way I wanted, changed it up, now it works. Don't like it, hate it, but it works."