# IE shows hidden options as blank, fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a SELECT in which several options are hidden by adding a class with `display: none;` depending on other conditions.

In most browsers this is fine, but in Internet Explorer 11 (sigh) this shows a blank row (see image).

Is there some CSS I can add to stop this from happening, or am I just doing this wrong?

I have removed all line feeds from inside the `SELECT` but this doesn't help.

The following shows the output in IE 11:

[image: SELECT showing empty rows in IE]

This is the source (formatting by Chrome - the CR's don't actually exist)
[image]

The relevent CSS:

```
.invisible {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Could you post some sample HTML (not all of it, it seems lenghty) and maybe even use a snippet to demonstrate your issue? Also congrats on your rep. It's beautiful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2324259/3233827

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo

Comment: Actually I had a horrible feeling this was the answer. Thanks all.