# Jquery Variable in $('option[title= look]').show();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
reviernummer.onchange = function(){
var look=$("#reviernummer").val();
    $("option[class='sorted']").hide();
    $("option[title=look]").show();
};
```

**The php code :**

```
<label style="width:100px;float:left;">f&uuml;r das Revier:*</label>
<select class="required"  id="reviernummer" style="width:240px;" name="verhaltenscode" ' >
<?php 
    $selected = $arrayAktuellerDatensatz['verhaltenscode'];?>
    <option selected ="selected" value="<?php echo $selected; ?>"><?php echo $selected; ?></option>
    <?php loadselect('kataster', 'Fischereibuchzahl', 'Fischereibuchzahl'); ?>
</select><br />

<select class="required" id="verhaltenscode" style="width:240px;" name="verhaltenscode">
    <?php $selected = $arrayAktuellerDatensatz['verhaltenscode_neu'];?>
    <option selected ="selected" value="<?php echo $selected; ?>"><?php echo $selected; ?></option>
    <?php loadselect('helpbrutstatus', 'Brutstatus', 'Brutstatus');?>
</select>
```

**loadselect function :**

```
if ($tblname == 'kataster'){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM kataster";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $fieldvalue = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
        $fieldcaption = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
        $lat = $row['Benennung']?>
        <option title="<?php echo $lat; ?>" value="<?php echo $fieldvalue;?>"><?php echo $fieldcaption .'&nbsp;|&nbsp;'.$lat?></option> <?php
    }
}
else if ($tblname == 'helpbrutstatus'){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM helpbrutstatus" ;

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $fieldvalue = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
        $status = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
        $fieldcaption = $row['Brutstatus']; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fieldvalue;?>" title="<?php echo $status;?>"  class="sorted">
        <?php echo $status."&nbsp;|&nbsp;".$fieldcaption?></option>  <?php


    }
}
```

I am trying to let all options disappear so i can make just some specific options be avaiable. What am i missing here in the last row of code? Can somebody help.

And sorry i couldn't find another answered question.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: post your html code also

Comment: You can't hide `option` elements (at least not in all browsers). You can only remove them and add them back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo

Comment: In what way is this failing?  Why do you have single-quotes around your `class` value, but not your `title` value?  Why are you creating the `look` variable and then never using it?  What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate String with variable using plus `+` signs, try the following code :

```
reviernummer.onchange = function(){
    var look=$("#reviernummer").val();

    $("option[class='sorted']").hide();
    $("option[title='"+look+"']").show();
};
```

---

It will be better if you can use jquery on change event, try also :

```
$('#reviernummer').on('change', function(){
    var look=$(this).val();

    $("option[class='sorted']").hide();
    $("option[title='"+look+"']").show();
};
```

Hope this helps.