# Keep list of options for select

Tags: javascript

Working with IE 10...so I can't just hide and show options in a select.

What if I remove certain options onchange with a JavaScript function, bit want these removed options stored somewhere so that if they change the previous selection again the function will remove the previous options and add the old ones thaf were first removed back in.  I hope this makes sense.

I have 2 selects.  My first select has two choices based on whatever is selected from this one the options for the second select will be removed or added.  By default, the 2nd select already has ALL options in it.  It is just disabled until the first select choice is picked.

Now I think what I can do is cloneNode the 2nd select to keep all options, but I would need this clone to be global so that I don't lose the removed options forever everytime my function runs.  However, global is bad.

I need all of this in HTML/Javascript.

*** All I have tried so far is the function to get all options of the 2nd select and to remove the options based on the ID of the options of the 2nd select, which is a code from the 1st select to filter the 2nd select . ***

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: I would suggest appending it your select object like this `document.getElementById("select").oldoptions = [your array of options] `. Use it to refresh every time

Comment: __All you have tried so far should be part of your question__

Comment: oldOptions is a new attribute u can create as many attributes in a javascript object for eg: `var a = {}; a.random1 = "sdsd"; a.random233 = "sadfsad"; `

Comment: Ok.  SO what I think I could do is make an array of objects that holds all of the properties of the removed options then append them back to the select.  Then onchange again save all the options to the object and remove/append again

Comment: Why not just append the options to a hidden select element? That would be a "legal" global storage.

Comment: Can't use jQuery.  How do I make a hidden select? Does IE 10 support hidden selects but not hidden options?

Comment: ??? With CSS: `display: none`.

Comment: Ok hidden select looks like it will work!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IE does not allow `display: none` on `<option>` elements. You must store a list of the options and construct the list of options when needed.

I created a simple `FilteredCollection` class which stores a source list and can return a filtered view without affecting the source array.

```js
// jQuery Plugins.
(function($) {
  // Populate a select input with options.
  $.fn.populateSelect = function(items, clear) {
    if (clear) this.empty();
    this.append(items.map(function(item) { return $('<option>', item); }));
  };
}(jQuery));

// A filtered collection view.
var FilteredCollection = function(source) {
  this.source = source;
};
FilteredCollection.prototype = {
  getSource : function()        { return this.source; },
  doFilter : function(filterFn) { return this.source.filter(filterFn); }
};

// Select options.
var makes = new FilteredCollection([
  { value : "1", text : "Ford" },
  { value : "2", text : "Toyota" },
  { value : "3", text : "General Motors" },
  { value : "4", text : "Honda" },
  { value : "5", text : "Hyundai" },
  { value : "6", text : "Volkswagen" },
  { value : "7", text : "Nissan" },
  { value : "8", text : "Peugeot" }
]);

// A state flag to flip for each change.
var state = 0;

$(function() {
  // Populate selection options.
  $('#make').populateSelect(makes.getSource());
  
  $('#make').on('change', function() {
    // Hide every even-indexed select option...
    $('#make option').each(function(index, option) {
      $('#make').populateSelect(makes.doFilter(function(item, index) {
        return index % 2 === state;
      }), true);
    });

    state ^= 1 // Flip the state.
  });
});
```

```css
select option.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="make"></select>
```

Comment: Setting the `<option>` to `display: none` [will not work in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2324259/1762224). SO storing them in a filtered array is the best solution.