# Hide dropdown field if already selected - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I currently have multiple drop-down lists with same values. Picking one would hide the value in the others. The following code works great, however does not seem to work in IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('select').on('change', function() {
  var selected = [];
  jQuery('select').each(function(){
    selected.push(jQuery(this).val());
  });
  jQuery('select option').each(function(){
    if(jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), selected) != -1) {
      jQuery(this).hide();
    }else{
      jQuery(this).show();
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [style.display='none' doesnt work on option tags in chrome, but it does in firefox, anyone know why? or a workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo)

Comment: The title there is for firefox, but it's the same with explorer